# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

Tab Отражает `Activity` состоящая из двух `Fragment`-ов `Activity`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="***.OtherFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fr_other" />

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="***.ButtonOrderFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment5"
        tools:layout="@layout/afr_application_form_subscription" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

здесь `OtherActivity.java:20` у меня `setContentView(R.layout.ac_other);`

и вот такая ошибка:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{******.OtherActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment  
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)  
    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1900)  
    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)  
    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)  
    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:694)  
    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:358)  
    at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:150)  
    at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:546)  
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)  
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)  
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)  
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)  
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)  
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)  
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)  
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)  
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)  
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment  
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)  
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)  
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)  
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)  
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)  
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)  
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)  
    at *****.OtherActivity.onCreate(OtherActivity.java:20)  
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)  
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)  
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)  
    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1900)   
    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)   
    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)   
    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:694)   
    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:358)   
    at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:150)   
    at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:546)   
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)   
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)   
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)   
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)   
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)   
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)   
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)   
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)   
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)   
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)   
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)   
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: *****.OtherFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment  
    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:577)  
    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:552)    
    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4656)  
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)  
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)   
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)   
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)   
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)   
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)   
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)   
    at ****.onCreate(OtherActivity.java:20)   
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)   
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)   
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)   
    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1900)   
    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)   
    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)   
    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:694)   
    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:358)   
    at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:150)   
    at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:546)   
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)   
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)   
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)   
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)   
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)   
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)   
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)   
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)   
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)   
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)   
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: нет такой вью - `<fragment...`, если хотите разместить фрагмент, используйте `<FrameLayout...`

Comment: @ermak0ff а есть такой "вью" include, merge, view? ошибка в том, что OtherFragment не является наследником android.app.Fragment. [клуц](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/174-urok-104-android-3-fragments-lifecycle.html)

Comment: @YuraIvanov да, действительно, есть такой способ подключения фрагментов через данный тэг, но как то в большинстве случаев используется динамическое подключение фрагментовю

Comment: @ermak0ff фрагменты - довольно мощный инструмент и их использование не ограничивается размещением в FrameLayout'е. Например, прием, используемый ТС, полезен для варианта поддержки разных разрешений, на телефоне - это один фрагмент, на планшете - два. Городить при этом FrameLayout'ы, динамически проверять существуют ли они, размещать в них фрагменты - лишний код и лишняя работа.

Comment: И вообще использование фрагментов не ограничивается отображением какой-то разметки, есть множество кейсов... Например, использование фрагментов как именованных объектов, привязанных к жизненному циклу активити... Это и фрагмент-кэш картинок текущей активити, и фрагмент-контейнер данных для всевозможных адаптеров и т.д.